# Reselect active object

Tags: blender

New to python scripting in Blender and wanting to do something relatively simple - create an object, duplicate it and translate the duplicated object, then reselect the original object. Here is my code using Blender 2.76:

```
import bpy
from bpy import context
original_object = bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add()
bpy.ops.object.duplicate()
bpy.ops.transform.rotate(value(90),axis=(1,0,0))
bpy.context.scene.objects.active = original_object
```

The last line is not working - the original object is not made active again. Wondering where the error is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This:

```
bpy.context.scene.objects.active = original_object
```

just sets the active object for the current Scene, but you also need to select it, which can be done using:

```
original_object.select = True
```

So, in your case you can write something like:

```
import bpy
from bpy import context

bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add()                  

original_object = bpy.context.scene.objects.active

bpy.ops.object.duplicate()
bpy.ops.transform.rotate(value=90,axis=(1,0,0))    # you need to put value=90 instead of value(90), otherwise you will get an error

for obj in bpy.context.selected_objects:           # deselects all selected objects
    obj.select = False

bpy.context.scene.objects.active = original_object
original_object.select = True
```